# How to show post using native Facebook app on android after fetching post ID?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

I'm trying to develop an Android app which interacts with Facebook using Graph API.

My plan is to display the original post on native Facebook app after getting the post ID.
I tried passing the URL `www.facebook.com/[post_id]` to browser and successfully displayed the post.

Is there any way to do this with the native Facebook app? I have tried using `fb://posts/[post_id]` and `fb://[post_id]` but both didn't work.

Any comment is appreciated :)

Comment: I am also working on this too, lets see if some one knows about it.